# Где найти алгоритм обработки «весов(параметров)» дерева для реализации бонусной системы как МММ?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, структуры-данных

Здравствуйте.
Необходимо разработать систему мотивации по привлечению клиентов на сайт, для того чтобы увеличить оборот денег.

Итак решено было использовать реферальные ссылки, те у определенного человека (человек К) есть ссылка, он дает ее друзьям\знакомым (человек N), они же при оформлении заказа на сайте вписывают эту реферальную ссылку (человека K) и получают свою аналогичную реферальную ссылку, которую уже могут дать другим людям..

Когда человек (человек N) оплачивает и получает свой заказ, который был оформлен с использованием реферальной ссылки, то (человек К) получает определенный процент, от этого заказа…

И так далее вниз по дереву: если (человека K) приводит своих людей (человек X) и когда они совершают заказ, то бонусы получают все вверх по дереву ( K -> X)...

Мне необходимо найти алгоритм (описание или название), который бы позволял это делать, буду реализовать на PHP.

НО так же необходимо вообще просчитать целесообразность и процент бонуса…
Например: я готов на бонусы потратить 10.000 (чтобы человек X получил 10.000), так вот, я хочу узнать какой процент для каждого уровня привлеченных нужно поставить и сколько уровней может быть и сколько узлов, чтобы корень дерева заработал 10.000 бонусов, ну и т.п, хочу поиграться и общим количеством бонусов, уровнями, узлами… чтобы прикинуть реальную ситуацию, возможно есть какой-то онлайн сервис, который позволяет делать подобное?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В целом, все  в вопросе - элементарная математика. И решается очень просто.

Но первое, что нужно сделать, это придумать, как хранить все данные. Я вижу таблицу (`users`) так:

```
int id // id пользователя, автоинкремент
int parent_id // id родителя, то есть того, кто будет получать процент
string name // имя/никнейм пользователя
string reference // строка для реферальной ссылки. должна быть уникальной
float percent // процент бонусов для дочерних
bool blocked // опционально, пользователь заблокирован
```

теперь основные моменты.

Когда человек регистрируется без реферальной ссылки, ему в parent_id записывается 0. Если же с ссылкой, то по ней находим "родителя" (`select id from users where refernce='...'`) и прописываем правильный parent_id.

проценты лучше хранить деленными на 100. То есть, если бонус 5 процентов, то храним как 0.05  - это сильно упростит расчеты.

Теперь, допустим, человек купил товар и нужно просчитать, кому сколько достанется. Тут есть разные системы, но обычно каждый человек получает процент от прибыли только своих подчиненных. Алгоритм расчета:

```
сумма = начальное-кол-во-бонусов
пока id не ноль
  по id находим родителя parent_id
  если это 0 - расчет завершен, выход

  получаем процент по parent_id
  сумма = сумма * процент
  это сумма бонусов для parent_id
  id = parent_id
```

Вторая задача - нужно рассчитать, сколько бонусов нужно дать на самому "нижнему", что бы самый "верхний" получил заданное. Тут алгоритм аналогичный, только начальную сумму считаем равной 1. В конце получим какое то маленькое число (при условии, что процент по бонусам всегда меньше 100%). Делим кол-во бонусов для верхнего на это маленькое число и получаем нужные бонусы в самом начале.

Если проценты у всех одинаковые, то задача сводиться к обычной [геометрической прогрессии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), которая достаточно хорошо изучена.